# Sending received data from a Waspmote Gateway to local database

Tags: xbee

I am working on a project using waspmote water flow sensors to capture flow rates and then send that data via a sensor network to a waspmote gateway using the 802.15.4 protocol. I have been able to successfully send data from my sensors to the waspmote gateway. How do I now send this data to my local database. Any Ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's a fairly broad question.  What have you connected the Waspmote Gateway to?  What programming language do you want to use?  What database?  You can use pretty much any language with a library to access the serial port of the Waspmote.  Process the serial data, and store it in your database.  What have you done so far, and where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a c# Webforms application that reads the serial data.
Use this program a base to work from: http://csharp.simpleserial.com/ There is only minimal changes to be made to make it read from a com port

You could then build a method to process the data coming through the serial, then  put it in an array which displays in a gridview.

Then you could Implement an SQL Database add tables and populate them with the data

You could then make a web application that reads from the Database to present the data in a way that looks nice.

That is just one way.